# heroku deployment - issue with www

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have deployed  my django app "myapp" to myapp.herokuapp.com

I own a domain www.example.com with godaddy

I have setup CNAME in my godaddy domain (www.example.com) to point to myapp.heroku.com

I have also added example.com and www.example.com as custom domains to my heroku app.

But, as of now, I am getting the app only at www.example.com and not at example.com(without www)

www.example.com gives me the default godaddy parked page.

What is the issue? How can I solve this?

Comment: CNAMES usually take 12 hours to update. If you're sure you updated it properly, just wait it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set a `CNAME` for the root `example.com`.

Even if it were possible, you probably wouldn't want to do it, since it would be saying "use the mail settings for `myapp.heroku.com` for `example.com`.

You would usually just set an A record for the root domain, but this is not possible because of heroku's dyamic routing.

The heroku docs suggest that you set an `ALIAS` or `ANAME` record (these are custom record types, dependent on your DNS provider), or set up a subdomain redirection from `example.com` to `www.example.com` See the [root domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain) section of the custom domains page on the heroku devcenter for more info.